# JS- Call a method from a generated button for a specific object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototypejs

I m new at coding , and I m searching for a way to launch a specific prototype method for each object of my array from a generated button

I've got json data to loop , and include each object on a js array.

//My data got 3 objects

```
var readArr = JSON.parse(myData)

var js_arr = [];
```

// loop on the array of object

```
for (var i = 0; i < readArr.length; i++) {

    var generatedObject = new Object();
```

//init method from prototype

```
    generatedObject.init(readArr[i].prop1, readArr[i].prop2, readArr[i].prop3, readArr[i].prop4, readArr[i].prop5,
            readArr[i].prop6, readArr[i].prop7, readArr[i].prop8);

    js_arr.push(generatedObject);
```

//generated a div which will contains a button for each occurence

```
    var newCntent = document.createElement('div');
    newCntent.id = readArr[i].prop1 + i;
    newCntent.className = "cntent";
    document.getElementById('zone_btn').appendChild(newCntent);
```

//create a button inside the div

```
    var newBtn = document.createElement('div');
    newBtn.id = i + readArr[i].prop1;
    newBtn.className = "etalonBtn";
    newBtn.innerHTML = readArr[i].prop1;
    document.getElementById(newCntent.id).appendChild(newBtn);
```

I've got a prototype method on my Object class and what I want is launch that method for each object linked with a button.
The first generated button will launch the method for js_arr[0], the second for js_arr[2],...how to code the fact that when I click on the button , the method must be call by "the object of the array which permetted your creation"

I don't have any clue on the way I can do this I tried several things:

```
newBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

       read_arr[i].DisplayUpdate();
    });

};
```

(returning read_arr[i] is not defined), so I just want to change that read_arr[i] by this now famous :"the object of the array which permetted your creation" ! 
 and I really need help on this...

Thank you by anticipation and sorry for this preschool english.

Comment: Where do you set the event listener?  is it inside the loop?

Comment: Yes it is, is it a bad idea ? The concept was to generate the button with the associated onclick event , but I don't know if it's relevant...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you're getting to the click function (i.e. - when actually clicking the button) you're already out of the loop, so js doesn't know what `'read_arr[i]'` is.

You need to pass `'read_arr[i]'` as a parameter to the function.
Basically something like this:

```
newBtn.addEventListener('click', function (object) {
       object.DisplayUpdate();
    },js_arr[i]);
```

This will change the function's signiture to also take a parameter- `object`, and also pass `js_arr[i]` as that parameter.

Hope that helps

Comment: New issue now , the debugger return : object.DisplayUpdate is not a function , it seems to didn't recognize my generated object as a similar of my class.

Comment: I tried to launch an alert on the onclick event  like  alert(JSON.stringify(object)); and it returns me {"is Trusted":true} instead of my object value , what does it means please ? And again I m sorry so I must misunderstand several things...

Answer (score 0):

you could also assign and bind the function to call when you create the button in your loop:

```
var newBtn = document.createElement('div');
    newBtn.id = i + readArr[i].prop1;
    newBtn.className = "etalonBtn";
    newBtn.innerHTML = readArr[i].prop1;
    newBtn.onclick = jsArr[i];
```